# convert a vector of complex numbers into a JSON array

Tags: c++, json, complex-numbers

add language identifier to highlight code, put returns between paragraphs, indent code by 4 spaces

```
#include "json.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

int main() {

struct {
    std::vector<std::complex<double>> Data;
} MESSAGE;

MESSAGE.Data = {{-3.2, 0.24}, {0.94, -9.3}};
}
```

I expect this JSON format

```
{
    "Data" : [ {"re": x, "im": y}, {"re": x, "im": y} ]
}
```

Comment: You can just iterate over your vector of `std::complex` and add it to your json object manually. Anyway, what kind of format do you expect? Array of json objects `{re: x, im: y}`, or sth different?

Comment: json has no data type for complex numbers. You need to specify how you want to store those values (maybe as pairs of numbers?). Are you required to work with SimpleJSON? There are other libraries, like [boost::json](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/json/doc/html/index.html), [json for modern C++](https://json.nlohmann.me/), or [rapidjson](https://rapidjson.org/) that can handle `std::vector` already.

Comment: @pptaszni, your remark is very correct, so I will add my question

Comment: @JakobStark, yes, there are a lot of other libraries, but I'd like to use SimpleJSON

Comment: @Putin_Caput the problem with SimpleJSON is, that it does not provide customization points. That means it is not designed to be expanded to support custom data types. You can write your own conversion function (like in the answer that pptaszni provided), but ultimately you will end up writing a lot of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds very straightforward. Extending my comment to an answer: just iterate over your elements and add them to json object:

```
  std::vector<std::complex<double>> data({{-3.2, 0.24}, {0.94, -9.3}});
  json::JSON obj;
  obj["Data"] = json::Array();
  for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    json::JSON num = {"re", data[i].real(), "im", data[i].imag()};
    obj["Data"][i] = num;
  }
  std::cout << obj << std::endl;
```

Note the unusual (for std containers) `obj["Data"][i]`. It looks like access out of bounds, but actually is not, because

```
        /// Access the elements of a JSON Array. 
        /// Accessing an out of bounds index will extend the Array.
        JSON& operator[]( unsigned index );
```

Answer (score 0):

You're problem can be divided into two subproblems. First we need a way to convert `std::complex` values to `json::JSON` objects. Then we need a way to convert `std::vector` values to `json::JSON` objects. Both can be done in a generic way (note that `std::complex` is not a class but a template). With the following function templates you should be able to convert your `std::vector<std::complex<double>>` into a simplejson container.

```
namespace json {

template<typename N>
JSON to_json(const std::complex<N>& c) {
    return {"re", c.real(), "im", c.imag() };
}

template<typename T>
JSON to_json(const std::vector<T>& vec) {
    JSON arr;
    for ( const auto& e : vec ) {
        arr.append(to_json(e));
    }
    return arr;
}

}
```

And use it like

```
std::vector<std::complex<double>> Data = {{-3.2, 0.24}, {0.94, -9.3}};
json::JSON jsonObj = {"Data", json::to_json(Data)};
std::cout << jsonObj;
```

which prints

```
{
  "Data" : [{
      "im" : 0.240000,
      "re" : -3.200000
    }, {
      "im" : -9.300000,
      "re" : 0.940000
    }]
}
```

---

You can easily expand those conversion functions. If for example you want to convert a `std::vector<std::string>`, just add a conversion function for `std::string` like the following:

```
JSON to_json(const std::string& s) {
    return JSON{s};
}
```

Comment: Cool explanation, thanks!
I see that the order of the real and imaginary parts has changed. And why?

Comment: And another question: why only 6 decimal places are saved? '"im" : 0.240000' Does this mean that there will be a loss of precision after converting from JSON to complex??

Comment: @Putin_Caput the order is changed by the simplejson library. I suspect it is because it uses `std::map` to store key value pairs internally. `std::map` is a sorted container, thus you will get an output with lexicographically sorted keys.

Comment: Concerning the precision, simplejson uses [std::to_string](https://github.com/nbsdx/SimpleJSON/blob/8dd3e9b84a0b532c46f22f402bafb2c4cf8621eb/json.hpp#L369) for the dump of `double` values. It implements [its own](https://github.com/nbsdx/SimpleJSON/blob/8dd3e9b84a0b532c46f22f402bafb2c4cf8621eb/json.hpp#L551) algorithm for parsing numbers from strings, which may or may not achieve lossless conversion of `double`s

Comment: @Putin_Caput I would recommend you to use another json library if you need precision guarantees. The source code that I've seen from simplejson is not written very well. I don't want to urge you to not use it, but it has not been updated since 2016, has a very small feature set compared to other libraries, and the code quality is poor.

Comment: According to [this benchmark](https://github.com/miloyip/nativejson-benchmark) the simplejson library (called nbsdx_SimpleJSON there) is one of the slowest, least json confomant, and overall worst libraries.

Comment: Really, RapidJSON is cooler than SimpleJSON. But it is also much more difficult. Could you show me how to do the same in RapidJSON:?